# Why does NewStaticCredentials return a blank Credentials object?

Tags: aws-sdk-go

I am trying to read S3 objects in Account A from Account B.
I am able to assume a role in Account B and retrieve `sts.Credentials` object.

```
stsClient := sts.New(session.Must(session.NewSession()))
params := &sts.AssumeRoleInput{
    RoleArn:         aws.String(roleArn),
    RoleSessionName: aws.String("role-session-name"),
}
stsResp, err := stsClient.AssumeRole(params)
checkErr(err)
// stsResp.Credentials.AccessKeyId     = ASIA...
// stsResp.Credentials.SecretAccessKey = abc...
// stsResp.Credentials.SessionToken    = xyz...
```

I then have to convert `sts.Credentials` object to a `credentials.Credentials` object in order to use it in

```
s3Client := s3.New(session.Must(session.NewSession()), &aws.Config{Credentials: creds})
```

However, when I do:

```
creds := credentials.NewStaticCredentials(*stsResp.Credentials.AccessKeyId, *stsResp.Credentials.SecretAccessKey, *stsResp.Credentials.SessionToken)
```

`creds` for some reason is a pointer to an empty `credentials.Credentials` object:

```
&{creds:{AccessKeyID: SecretAccessKey: SessionToken: ProviderName:} forceRefresh:true m:{state:0 sema:0} provider:0xc4201a2840}
```

I have also tried:

```
values, err := creds.Get()
checkErr(err)
fmt.Println(values) // prints out credentials values as expected
```

So, it's not quite clear to me why `credentials.NewStaticCredentials()` returns an empty credentials object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When printing out the [`credentials.Credentials`](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/blob/master/aws/credentials/credentials.go#L155) value returned by `credentials.NewStaticCredentials()` the `creds` value you see printed is the cached AWS credentials stored in the `Credentials` type that has not been populated yet. This field is populated when `Credentials.Get` is called. The value is invalid prior to Get being called.

The [`NewStaticCredentials`](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/blob/master/aws/credentials/static_provider.go#L25) will create a [`StaticProvider`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/aws/credentials/#StaticProvider) value which satisfies the [`Provider`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/aws/credentials/#Provider) interface. The `Credentials` type will use the [`Provider.Retrieve()`](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/blob/master/aws/credentials/credentials.go#L185) method to retrieve the latest credential `Values` from the Provider. The `Credentials` type will cache the `creds` response from `Retrieve()` until the `Provider` flags the credentials as [expired](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/blob/master/aws/credentials/credentials.go#L221). In the case of `StaticProvider` the credentials never expire.

This is why `creds.Get()` returns the values without an error. If you were to print `creds` after `Get` was called you'd see the cached static values in the `Credentials` type.

Comment: Thank you. Calling `creds.Get()` before my `s3.GetObject()` worked.